# Loading Userform with Recordet Information Of Selected Item (How to make faster)

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, userform

Im having a very minor issue, but is an issue nonetheless and its driving me nuts!

I have a Userform (VBA, using Excel as the Front End and Access as the Back End) which hast textboxes and a listbox.

What it does is fill the textboxes with information from an Access Database based on the selection the user makes on the listbox.

So if the user selects the entry with the "001" code, it goes to the Access DB, fecthes that record and populates the UserForm.

Below is the code:

```
Private Sub LtaInversiones_Click()

Dim rcon As Recordset
Dim sql As String

sql = "SELECT * FROM INVERSIONES WHERE CODIGO = "_
& LtaInversiones.List(LtaInversiones.ListIndex, 0)

Set rcon = BD.OpenRecordset(sql)

With rcon

    CmbCodigo.Text = !Codigo
    CmbTipo.Text = !TIPO
    TxtTitulo.Text = !TITULO
    TxtMonto.Text = !Monto
    DTFCompra.Value = !FECHACOMPRA
    DTFVencimiento.Value = !FECHAVENCIMIENTO
    CmbPeriodicidad.Text = !periodicidad
    TxtTCupon.Text = !TASACUPON
    TxtPrecio.Text = !Precio
    TxtRendimiento.Text = !rendimiento
    TxtGPRedencion.Text = !GANANCIAPERDIDAREDENCION
    TxtIAcum.Text = !INTERESESACUMULADOS
    CmbEmisor.Text = !eMISOR
    CmbOperador.Text = !OPERADOR
    TxtNotas.Text = !NOTAS

        If !FECHAREDENCION <> "" Then

             DTFRedencion.Value = !FECHAREDENCION
             ChkCInversion.Value = True

        Else

             ChkCInversion.Value = False


        End If

    .Close

End With

    Set rcon = Nothing
    CmdEliminar.Visible = True
    CmdGuardar.Caption = "Modificar"
    CmbCodigo.Enabled = True
```

The thing is, its working, but it slows down a bit. Ive tested the possible reasons, and it is definitely the fact that the query has to go look at what the list index is before going to the DB.

So I would like to ask you more experienced programmers (Im a lawyer by trade :/ ) If there is a better way of doing this.

The only thing that has ocurred to me is maybe loading all the records on initialization and then somehow accessing that data, as that would prevent the trip to the DB but am unsure whether that would improve performance or how to do it for that matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from changing this:

```
LtaInversiones.List(LtaInversiones.ListIndex, 0)
```

to this?

```
LtaInversiones.Value
```

This will avoid a double lookup (List & ListIndex)

I personally avoid the "!" notation, preferring the fuller .Fields("ABC").Value 
I'm not sure of any performance penalty or advantage there.

Comment: I tried it, and nothing was stopping me aside from ignorance lol. However, it didnt make an improvement on speed. As a comparison, I hard coded a random number and it was fast enough for it to be unperceptible (as it is right now, it takes around 1.5 to 2 secs to get things to change in my code)